# In fp-ts, how to compose 2 (or more) Ord instances

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

Say I have a list of strings and I want to sort them first by string length and then alphabetically (so strings within the list with the same length are sorted alphabetically).

I already have `ordString` which can be used to sort alphabetically. I can make my own `Ord` instance for string length:

```
import * as S from 'fp-ts/string'
import * as N from 'fp-ts/number'
import * as Ord from 'fp-ts/Ord'

const ordString = S.Ord

const ordStringLength = pipe(N.Ord, Ord.contramap((s: string) => s.length))
```

If I want to use these `Ord`s to sort my list I can call `A.sort` twice, but this seems wasteful:

```
import * as A from 'fp-ts/Array'

const sorted = pipe(listOfStrings, A.sort(ordString), A.sort(ordStringLength))
```

Is there a way I can compose the `ordString` and `ordStringLength` instances into a single instance that can be used in a single call to `A.sort`?

(this is a contrived example to demonstate my question; in reality the ordering is more complex and may involve combining several `Ord`s)

Comment: I'm not certain, because I'm not an `fp-ts` user, but I see that `Ord` has a semigroup instance, which is probably what you want

Comment: I think that's the answer. Now just need to figure out how to build the appropriate semigroup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Ord` has a `Monoid` instance, which can be used to do what you want; that is, first order with one `Ord`, then with another.

There's a pretty good example in the `fp-ts` [docs](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/60250b9de118d4939374368ca1be665bac871769/docs/modules/Ord.ts.md#getmonoid)

in short, you should be able to do

```js
import { sort } from 'fp-ts/Array'
import { getMonoid } from 'fp-ts/Ord'
import { concatAll } from 'fp-ts/Monoid'

const M = getMonoid<string>
const byBothOrds = concatAll(M)([ordString, ordStringLength])
const sorted = sort(byBothOrds)(listOfStrings)
```

It should be fairly obvious how to add additional `Ord`s to this, as you asked.

Comment: is there a good guide for fp-ts? As far as I understood, in order to lear fp-ts you need to read source code :(

Comment: In fairness, I both could, and should, have linked to the docs, rather than the sourcecode

Comment: thank you. I'm trying to learn fp-ts, some times it looks quite unreadable, at least for me

Comment: Nice. I actually went with `Ord.getSemigroup<string>().concat(ordStringLength, ordString)` which seems to do the trick.

Comment: For clarification: `Ord` is a type class and thus cannot be an instance of another one. The only relation between type classes are sub-/superclass. But the `Ordering` data type has an `Monoid` instance. `Ordering` is just a type wrapper around the `-1/0/1` comparator.